# How to sample dates of the same weekday?

Tags: r, date, time, weekday

Considering the date samples:

```
t_s<-seq(as.POSIXct("2010-01-01 00:00:00"), as.POSIXct("2010-12-31 23:00:00"), by = '1 day')
```

and a date vector:

```
t<-seq(as.POSIXct("2010-02-01 00:00:00"), as.POSIXct("2010-2-10 23:00:00"), by = '1 day')
```

Now, I want to randomly sample dates in `t_s` with the same weekday of the elements in `t`.The sample size should be 4 for each `t` element.
For example, the samples for the first element `"2010-02-01"` could be `"2010-06-28" "2010-5-31" "2010-8-02" "2010-10-04"` because they are all Monday.

The sampled dates from `t_s` maybe multipul, beacause some dates in `t` share a same weekday. However, if `t_s` is much smaller than `t`(not in the examplified case), the uniqueness of samples cannot be met. Therefore, sample methods with and without multipul `t_s` dates are both wanted.

How could I get these samples?

Comment: One way could be `n <- 4L;lapply(format(t, "%w"), function(wday) sample(t_s[wday==format(t_s, "%w")], n))`. There may be better options though.

Comment: Please clarify whether or not sampled dates from `t_s` can appear for  multiple dates in `t`.

Comment: @nrussell I've edited the question for further clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do what you need

### Without replacement

```
lapply(seq_along(t), function(x){
  sample(t_s[weekdays(t_s)==weekdays(t[x])], 4, replace = FALSE)
})
```

### With replacement

```
lapply(seq_along(t), function(x){
  sample(t_s[weekdays(t_s)==weekdays(t[x])], 4, replace = TRUE)
})
```

These return a list with your samples

### Excluding previously selected dates

```
# Based on @lmo comment
ds <- c()
lapply(seq_along(t), function(x){
  if(x == 1){ result <- sample(t_s[weekdays(t_s)==weekdays(t[x])], 4)
} else {
  t_s2 <- t_s[!(t_s %in% ds)]
  result <- sample(t_s2[weekdays(t_s2)==weekdays(t[x])], 4)
}
ds <<- c(ds, result)
result
})
```

Comment: This could result in the same date in t_s being selected more than once for weekdays in t. For example, there are 2 Mondays in t. Not sure what the OP wants regarding this.

Comment: Correct, but as you stated the OP hasn't specified this. I will try to update for this case

Comment: @imo I've edited the question for further clarification.